# Not able to find the element in cypress

Tags: css-selectors, cypress

This is my html tag(highlighted one):

[image]

I am trying to click with cypress, however cypress is not able to find it, this is what i am using:

```
cy.get('sg_button sg newflex hbox acenter ').click()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), e.g.:

```js
'.sg_button.sg.newflex.hbox.acenter'
```

You should try the selector playground feature of Cypress, which will give you the answer:

[image]
[image]

Comment: yes but the problem is that selector that cypress selects which is id in this case is dynamic id and it changed everytime

Comment: no it does not work, it says - CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 6 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.

Comment: no it does not work, it says - CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 6 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.

Comment: ok, there you go, so either use `.first().click`, or use `{multiple:true}`. Could you accept the answer?

Comment: no it should click that. does not work but does not give any error either

Comment: Make sure you&#39;re getting the correct element with .first, otherwise use .eq(n) to get the nth element

Comment: it is saying CypressError: cy.eq() failed because it requires a DOM element.

Comment: At this point, the best way I can help you is to point you to the docs. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#